# Rebuilding Column Names in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe like this:

```
   Height  Speed
0     4.0   39.0
1     7.8   24.0
2     8.9   80.5
3     4.2   60.0
```

Then, through some feature extraction, I get this:

```
0    39.0
1    24.0
2    80.5
3    60.0
```

However, I want it to be a dataframe where the column index is still there.  How would you get the following?

```
   Speed
0   39.0
1   24.0
2   80.5
3   60.0
```

I am looking for an answer that compares the original with the new column and determines that the new column must be named Speed.  In other words, it shouldn't just rename the new column 'Speed'.

Here is the feature extraction: Let *X* be the original dataframe and *X1* be the returned array that lacks a column name.

```
    svc = SVC(kernel="linear")
    rfecv = RFECV(estimator=svc, step=1, cv=StratifiedKFold(2),
                  scoring='accuracy')
    X1=rfecv.fit_transform(X, y)
```

Thanks

EDIT:

For the comments I am receiving, I will clarify my ambiguity.  I believe that the feature extraction method above takes a dataframe or a series/array.  Then, it returns an array.  I am passing a dataframe into it. This dataframe contains the column labels and the data.  However, it returns an array that lacks column names.  Another caveat is that this must be ambiguous in general.  I cannot explicitly name my columns because the columns will change in my program.  It could return two arrays, four arrays, ...  I am looking for a method that will compare the original dataframe to the array(s) given after the feature extraction and realize that the new array is "subset" of the original dataframe. Then, mark it with the orginal column name(s).  Let me know your thoughts on that!  Sorry guys and thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the code that produces the feature extraction? Please include that.

Comment: Is that important?    I don't want to include code that isn't needed.  Essentially it takes a dataframe column and turns it into a np.array which lacks  a column name.  I will post code if you feel it is essential to this question being answered correctly.

Comment: Yes, because if you can modify that code to retain the DataFrame, why let it break to fix it later? Prevention is better than a cure, don't you agree?

Comment: Done. Thanks~~~

Comment: Hmm, maybe you can consider passing a 2D array instead of 1D? Where has X come from? Did you do `X = df['col']`? Try instead something like `X = df[['col']]`

Comment: @coldspeed is right. Leaving the question as it is the feature could be a Series or a Dataframe. Basically why try to answer to discover that you meant a different object. Please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)

Comment: Good thought. However,  `X=df.drop(df[target],axis=1)`

Comment: Please see new edit. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFECV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html), after being fit, has an attribute called `support_`, which is a boolean mask of selected features. You can obtain the names of the chosen features by doing:

`selected_cols = original_df.columns[rfecv.support_]`

Easy peasey!